# Site scaling to browser window size

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I try to make responsive website to scaling browser window size. I dont know why it`s not working, I do not want this scroll bar.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t678vbb8/15/)

```
        html 
        {
          font: normal normal 12px/1 Calibri;    
          font-weight: bold;
          color:#666;
        }   
        body
        {

            background-color:#f1f1f1;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
        }
        .box
        {
            padding:20px;
            background-color:#fff;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius:5px;
   }
```

[image]

Comment: your question is very unclear. Please explain more what you are getting now and what result would you expect instead

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: you don't want scroll bar. but what do you want ? tables columns do not work like bootstrap columns for example. To go 1 after the other when the window resizes. You will need to change the default behavior of the table element for that. Can you be more specific of what you want? Not what you don't want

Answer (score 0):

please go through [this](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/)

Create responsive tables by adding .table-responsive to any .table to make them scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide